# periodic flushing during mybatis batch execution

Tags: spring, mybatis

My batched statements in mybatis are timing out. I'd like to throttle the load I'm sending to the database by flushing the statements periodically. In iBATIS, I used a callback, something like this:

```
        sqlMapClientTemplate.execute(new SqlMapClientCallback<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapExecutor executor)
                    throws SQLException {
                executor.startBatch();
                int tally = 0;
                for (Foo foo: foos) {
                        executor.insert("FooSql.insertFoo",foo.getData());
                        /* executes batch when > MAX_TALLY */
                    tally = BatchHelper.updateTallyOnMod(executor, tally);
                }
                return executor.executeBatch();
            }
        });
```

Is there a better way to do this in mybatis? Or do I need to do the same type of thing with SqlSessionCallback? This feels cumbersome. What I'd really like to do is configure the project to flush every N batched statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not get any responses, so I'll share the solution I settled on.

Mybatis provides direct access to statement flushing. I autowired the SqlSession, used Guava to partition the collection into manageable chunks, then flushed the statements after each chunk.

```
Iterable<List<Foo>> partitions = Iterables.partition(foos, MAX_TALLY);
for (List<Foo> partition : partitions) {
    for (Foo foo : partition) {
        mapper.insertFoo(foo);
    }
    sqlSession.flushStatements();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late response, but I just stumbled onto this question right now. However, hopefully it will help others with a similar problem.

You don't need to explicitly Autowire the SqlSession. You may use the mapper interface itself. In the mapper interface simply define a method that is annotated with the `@Flush` annotation and has a return type of `List<BatchResult>`. Here's an example of a method in the mapper interface:

```
@Flush
List<BatchResult> flushBatchedStatements();
```

Then simply call this method on your mapper object like so:

```
Iterable<List<Foo>> partitions = Iterables.partition(foos, MAX_TALLY);
for (List<Foo> partition : partitions)
{
    for (Foo foo : partition)
    {
        mapper.insertFoo(foo);
    }
    mapper.flushBatchedStatements(); //this call will flush the all statements batched upto this point, into the table.
}
```

Note that you don't need to add anything special into your mapper XML file to support this type of statement flushing via the mapper interface. Your XML mapper may simply be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >

<mapper namespace=".....">

    <insert id="bulkInsertIntoTable" parameterType="myPackage.Foo">

        insert into MyDatabaseTable(col1, col2, col3)
        values
        ( #{fooObj.data1}, #{fooObj.data2}, #{fooObj.data3} )

    </insert>

</mapper>
```

The only thing that is needed is that you use MyBatis 3.3 or higher. Here's what the MyBatis docs on the MyBatis website state:

> If this annotation is used, it can be called the
>   SqlSession#flushStatements() via method defined at a Mapper
>   interface.(MyBatis 3.3 or above)

For more details please visit the MyBatis official documentation site:
http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html